# Angular 9 this._datepicker._registerInput is not a function at MatDatepickerInput.set [as matDatepicker]

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular9

**UPDATE**
Modified code, deleted one of the two #pickerDal

I have migrated an Angular 8 project to Angular 9 but the datepicker is giving errors. I have:

```
this._datepicker._registerInput is not a function
    at MatDatepickerInput.set [as matDatepicker]
```

This is my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.7.1",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^9.1.11",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor": "^18.3.47",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^4.1.0",
    "ajv": "^6.9.1",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^9.2.2",
    "cdk-table-exporter": "^9.0.2",
    "chalk": "^3.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "devexpress-diagram": "^1.0.17",
    "devexpress-gantt": "^1.0.10",
    "devextreme": "^20.2.3",
    "devextreme-angular": "20.2.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^9.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.10",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^9.1.10",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^9.1.10",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~6.0.1",
    "devextreme-cli": "1.2.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "json-server": "^0.12.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
```

And this is my datepicker:

```
<mat-form-field >
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerDal"
          (dateChange)="fromDate('change', $event)" formControlName="dal"
          (focus)="pickerDal.open()" readonly [(ngModel)]="dal_default">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerDal"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #pickerDal></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
```

What I do in my .ts is just:

```
  @ViewChild("pickerDal", {
    read: MatInput,
    static: true,
  })
  pickerDal: MatInput;
```

I've deleted node-modules folder and reinstalled everything. I can't change versions of the libraries.
Any clue?

Comment: this is happening for me also on angular 12

Answer (score 1):

The error is come from ngModel. When you use ngModel within a form tag, the name attribute must be set.

```html
<mat-form-field >
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerDal"
          (dateChange)="fromDate('change', $event)" formControlName="dal"
          (focus)="pickerDal.open()" readonly [(ngModel)]="dal_default" name="dal_default">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerDal"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #pickerDal></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
```

This works for me.